# Oracle Joining 2 Select Statements With Only One Record From Each Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I have 2 queries that needs to be run. I am trying to retrieve the first record of each query and combining them together.

Summary of the question: Get top scorers of both category, senior and over60, and display the results.

Below is the query that I am running:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT C2.*, RE.POINTS
FROM COMPETITION C1, COMPETITOR C2, RESULTS RE, REGISTRATION REG
WHERE REG.CATEGORYTYPE IN ('SENIOR')
AND C1.TIMEPLANNED BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-15') AND TO_DATE ('31-DEC-15')
AND REG.COMPETITIONID = RE.COMPETITONID
AND RE.COMPETITORID = C2.COMPETITORID
AND RE.COMPETITONID = C1.COMPETITIONID
ORDER BY RE.POINTS DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

The second query is very similar to the first, only making changes in the `categorytype`

```
WHERE REG.CATEGORYTYPE IN ('OVER60')
```

May I know how can I go about joining these 2 statements together?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need these two tables: `COMPETITION C1, COMPETITOR C2, ` ? the C1 table seems irrelevant since you are returning only data from C2 `C2.*`

Comment: My apologies. I have added a date factor in the query which I didnt put in the post. I have edited my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT * FROM
 ( 
   SELECT C2.*, RE.POINTS,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY REG.CATEGORYTYPE
            ORDER BY RE.POINTS DESC) AS rn
   FROM COMPETITION C1, COMPETITOR C2, RESULTS RE, REGISTRATION REG
   WHERE REG.CATEGORYTYPE IN ('SENIOR', 'OVER60')
     AND C1.TIMEPLANNED BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-15') AND TO_DATE ('31-DEC-15')
     AND REG.COMPETITIONID = RE.COMPETITONID
     AND RE.COMPETITORID = C2.COMPETITORID
     AND RE.COMPETITONID = C1.COMPETITIONID
 )
WHERE rn=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Add this in your where clause REG.CATEGORYTYPE in('senior','over60')